# Why putchar is printing some numerical value instead of a char i asked it to put?

Tags: c

im trying to print out the actual \t, and \b when i get from the input those actions.

```
 int main()

    {

        int input, specialChar;

        while ((input = getchar()) != EOF)

            specialChar = 0;

        {

            if (input == '\t')

            {
                putchar('\\');
                putchar('t');  
                specialChar = 1;
            }
```

is putchar('t');  not suppose to print out "t" ?

```
    if (input == '\b')

        {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('b');
            specialChar = 1;

        }


        if (specialChar == 0)

            putchar(input);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Could you please tell me why do i get "\377" instead?

Comment: Is your while loop correct?  Is `specialChar=0` supposed to be inside the braces instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your loop is:

```
    while ((input = getchar()) != EOF)
        specialChar = 0;
```

Then, when you exit the loop, you get to:

```
    {

        if (input == '\t')

        {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('t');  
            specialChar = 1;
        }
```

Which means you get to the:

```
    if (specialChar == 0)
        putchar(input);
```

withn an "EOF" in input, which, as a character is 0xff, 255 or 0377 in hex, decimal and octal respectively.

Move your braces around so it covers the whole loop!